# How to reduce a unuse css file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using bootstrap to build a mobile web page

only one page and use some of the bootstrap css and js code but I have to hold all the css and js.

since I only use some of it I want to reduce the unused css style and js code to reduce the file size

how to do it?

I mean if I only use the modal of the bootstrap how to reduce the css of col and alert and other css I do not used?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not fully sure if this question really belongs here, but there is an answer to the question.

You can use Bootstrap's site to customize which elements of bootstrap you want and do not want, downloading a file with only the bits that you would like to keep.

This is available here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/

Comment: I am not only find the bootstrap I am looking for how to do it even in other css files

Comment: With your own CSS files, you can use something like PurifyCSS or the Dev tools built into most modern browsers to find unused rules, then remove them from your files using your text editor of choice.  This is trickier with CSS libraries that you didn't write yourself, but most, like Bootstrap, have some kind of customization page for you to use.

Comment: Thank you that's what I need .I know it is bootstrap not write myself and I will not tell others it is write by me . and I will keep the bootstrap css style such as col-2

Answer (score 0):

Remove Unused CSS from the Stylesheet
Here’s how you can easily find all the unused selectors in your CSS files in Google Chrome:

Open any page of your website inside Google Chrome and then launch the Dev Tools available under File -> Tools -> Developers Tools.
Click the Audits tab inside Dev Tools and select the “Web Page Performance” and “Reload Page and Audit on Load” options. Now click the “Run” button to begin the CSS audit process.
On the results page, expand the “Remove Unused CSS Rules” group and select the CSS file(s) that are linked from your site. You may ignore the CSS files added by social plugins and widgets since you do not have control over them.
Here you will get a sorted list of all styles that are defined in the CSS file but not used anywhere on the current page.

You can copy and save the results in a text file and repeat the steps for couple of other pages on your site. This is essential as not all selectors may be used on all pages. You can find the count of various selectors in the combined resultset, maybe using Google Sheets, and the selectors with the highest count can probably be “safely” removed.

read more [this link](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/remove-unused-css)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome DevTools has coverage tool. It identifies which code is useful and which is not. I used it to reduce my css file from ~25K lines to ~2.3k lines.

Read more here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/coverage

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to reduce the size of your Bootstrap CSS and JS files when you are only using a small portion of the framework:

**1. Use the Bootstrap CDN:**

This is the simplest option. The Bootstrap CDN provides pre-compiled minified versions of the CSS and JS files for each Bootstrap version. You can include only the specific files you need, which will reduce the amount of unnecessary code downloaded.

Here's an example of how to include only the modal component:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

**2. Use the Bootstrap Customize site:**

This site allows you to select the specific Bootstrap components you need and download a custom CSS and JS file that only includes those components. This is a good option if you want to avoid downloading any unnecessary code, but it requires more configuration than using the CDN.

**3. Use a CSS minifier:**

There are many online tools and command-line utilities that can minify your CSS code. This process removes whitespace, comments, and other unnecessary characters, which can significantly reduce the file size.

**4. Use a JS minifier:**

Similar to CSS minifiers, JS minifiers can remove unnecessary characters and whitespace from your JS code to reduce its size.

**5. Use Sass/LESS:**

If you are comfortable with Sass or LESS, you can download the Bootstrap source files and compile them yourself. This allows you to exclude the components you don't need, which can significantly reduce the size of your CSS and JS files.

Here are some additional tips for reducing Bootstrap file size:

- Use the "minified" versions of the CSS and JS files. These versions have already been minified and will be smaller than the unminified versions.
- Gzip your CSS and JS files. This will compress them further, reducing their size by up to 90%.
- Preload the critical CSS. This is the CSS that is needed to render the initial content of the page. By preloading it, you can improve the page's loading speed.

**Specific to your case:**

Since you only need the modal component, you can use any of the methods mentioned above to exclude the unused CSS and JS code related to col, alert, and other components. Here are some specific examples:

- **Using the Bootstrap Customize site:** Select only the "Modal" component and download the custom CSS and JS files.
- **Using Sass/LESS:** Import only the mixins and variables related to the modal component when compiling the Bootstrap source files.
- **Manually removing unused code:** Open the Bootstrap CSS file and remove all the styles related to col, alert, and other components you don't need.

By following these tips, you can significantly reduce the size of your Bootstrap CSS and JS files, which can improve the performance of your mobile web page.